# How to save a Unity GameObject with Odin Serializer?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to dynamically compose a Unity GameObject at runtime and then serialize it using Odin Serializer but cannot get it to work.  What's the best way to do this?

Here's a simple repro; attach this to an empty game object in a scene and run it:

```
public class TestComponent : SerializedMonoBehaviour
{
    public int testValue = 100;
}

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var go = new GameObject();
        go.AddComponent<TestComponent>();

        byte[] bytes = SerializationUtility.SerializeValue(go, DataFormat.JSON);
        File.WriteAllBytes("testOutput", bytes);
    }
}
```

When that code is run, here are the contents of the 'testOutput' file:

```
{
    "$id": 0,
    "$type": "0|UnityEngine.GameObject, UnityEngine.CoreModule"
}
```

I was expecting to see 'TestComponent' referenced in the testOutput file.